# Calculating natural rate of unemployment

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear-algebra, macroeconomics

I have sample data on unemployment rate in a market and am looking to calculate the natural unemployment rate. The natural unemployment rate I obtained is constant over a time period, which is not a realistic assumption given the fluctuations we observe in labor force, employment.

As per the keynesian [relationship between unemployment and inflation](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-economics/chapter/the-relationship-between-inflation-and-unemployment/#:%7E:text=The%20Phillips%20curve%20argues%20that,%2C%20however%2C%20is%20not%20linear.&text=Theoretical%20Phillips%20Curve%3A%20The%20Phillips,off%20between%20inflation%20and%20unemployment.), the natural rate is defined as rate when inflation is stable or change in inflation is 0.

```
Pandas DataFrame: 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Date_Col': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2010', periods=40, freq='3M'),
                   'unemployment': np.random.uniform(5,12,40),
                   'Inflation': np.random.uniform(1,3, 40)
                  })

df['Change_Inflation'] = df['Inflation'].pct_change(periods=1)

# Drop first row
df1 = df[2:len(df)]
df1
```

I fit the following regression model to obtain estimates and calculate the natural level of unemployment:

```
change in inflation = b0 + b1 * unemployment + e
```

Substituting, `change in inflation = 0`, and solving for `unemployment`, the `natural unemployment rate = b0/b1`. The rate I obtained is for entire time period, this isn't realistic as there are significant supply side fluctuations in labor force. Therefore, I'd like to calculate the natural rate for each time period. How would I do so?

Comment: What you are looking for is not just a question of statistics but also, in fact mainly, economics. [Economics Stackexchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this.

Comment: This is a fine statistical question: you are asking for a method to estimate a differentiable smooth of the time series.  Econometricians could probably advise you on their conventional methods to do this, whereas here on CV we can propose a huge variety of methods.  On that basis you still might want to migrate this question.  If so, just flag it for migration and we'll do it for you.

Comment: @whuber I posted this question separately on https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/calculating-natural-rate-of-unemployment

Comment: That wasn't a great idea, because now your question will be addressed in two separate threads, which is both inefficient and confusing.  A cross-post on SE implies a commitment on your part to share the answers and other information you get on one site with all the other cross-posted sites (which is a pain).

Comment: @whuber got it. I'll keep in that in mind for next time, wasn't aware of cross-posting.